# Toggle div size on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make div bigger on click. After clickig again, I'd like to make the div small. Is there a way to do this? And could I add animation to it?

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.hud-map')) return;
  event.preventDefault();
  var map = document.getElementById("hud-map");
  map.style.height = "200px";
  map.style.width = "200px";
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="hud-map" class="hud-map" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;
 border-radius: 1em; color: rgb(211, 84, 0); border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);">

</div>
```

Comment: toggle a class, so much easier `map.classList.toggle("large")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like the following and for animation, you just need to add `transition` to your element:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.hud-map')) return;
  event.preventDefault();
  var map = document.getElementById("hud-map");
  if (map.style.width === '200px') {
    map.style.height = "100px";
    map.style.width = "100px";  
  } else {
    map.style.height = "200px";
    map.style.width = "200px";
  }

}, false);
```

```html
<div id="hud-map" class="hud-map" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;
 border-radius: 1em; color: rgb(211, 84, 0); border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);transition: all 200ms ease;">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to handle the animation with something like `transition: all .5s;`, and to handle the toggling of the size, a ternary condition like `(map.style.height == '200px') ? "100px" : "200px";`

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.hud-map')) return;
  event.preventDefault();
  var map = document.getElementById("hud-map");
  map.style.height = (map.style.height == '200px') ? "100px" : "200px";
  map.style.width = (map.style.width == '200px') ? "100px" : "200px";
}, false);
```

```css
#hud-map {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 1em;
  color: rgb(211, 84, 0);
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="hud-map" class="hud-map">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just toggle a class and use css transition to animate the changing of the size

```js
document.querySelector('.map').addEventListener('click', function () {
  this.classList.toggle('large')
})
```

```css
div.map {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s;
}

div.map.large {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var isClicked = false;
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.hud-map')) return;
  event.preventDefault();
  var map = document.getElementById("hud-map");
  map.style.width = (isClicked ? 100 : 200) + 'px';
  map.style.height = (isClicked ? 100 : 200) + 'px';
  isClicked = isClicked ? false : true;
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="hud-map" class="hud-map" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;
     border-radius: 1em; color: rgb(211, 84, 0); border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

CSS transitions seem like the simplest approach here; simply add and remove classes in your event handler, which should be tied to the element rather than the entire document:

```js
document.getElementById("hud-map").addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.className.includes("hud-map-sm")) {
    e.target.classList.remove("hud-map-sm");
    e.target.classList.add("hud-map-lg");
  }
  else {
    e.target.classList.remove("hud-map-lg");
    e.target.classList.add("hud-map-sm");    
  }
});
```

```css
.hud-map {
  border-radius: 1em;
  color: rgb(211, 84, 0);
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transition: 1s;
}

.hud-map-sm {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;  
}

.hud-map-lg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hud-map" class="hud-map hud-map-sm">
</div>
```

[Toggling a single CSS class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52560076/6243352) is probably better but I'll leave this up for times when it might make sense to have two separate ones.